# MS Access Query Syntax Error in FROM

Tags: sql, ms-access

For an assignement I have to write SQL out to display Customer's Last name, order date, product ID, fabric of the product, quantity ordered, and unit price. This must be a 4-table join and must user INNERJOIN even if where can be used.

These are the tables involved.

Cus (**CID**, Last, First, Phone)
Orders (**OrdID**, OrdDate, ShipDate, CID)
Manu (**ManuID**, Name, Phone, City)
Prods (**PrID**, ManuID, Category)
ProdFabric (**PrID**, **Fabric**, Price)
Orderline (**OrdId**, **PrID**, **Fabric**, Qty)

Bold means it is a primary key or part of a composite key.

Here is the query I entered, but I keep getting a syntax error on FROM and it
keeps highlighting Orders (after Cus INNERJOIN) for some reason.

```
SELECT Last, OrdDate, Prods.PrID, Fabric, Qty, Price  
FROM Cus INNERJOIN Orders INNERJOIN Orderline INNERJOIN ProdFabric   
ON OrderLine.PrID=ProdFabric.PrID  
AND ON Orderline.Fabric=ProdFrabric.Fabric  
AND ON Cus.CID=Orders.CID  
AND ON Orders.OrdID=Orderline.OrdID;
```

What causes this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK MS Access requires a Lisp-like proliferation of parentheses to support multiple joins.

- Edit your MS Access queries in another editor that supports paren-matching and syntax-highlighting, e.g. Notepad++.
- Use table aliases to keep your queries shorter and more manageable.

With the parentheses, your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT c.Last
       , o.OrdDate
       , pf.PrID
       , pf.Fabric
       , ol.Qty
       , pf.Price
FROM   ((Cus c
       INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CID = o.CID)
       INNER JOIN Orderline ol ON o.OrdID = ol.OrdID)
       INNER JOIN ProdFabric pf ON ol.PrID = pf.PrID;
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Got it working with the parenthesis. Although, when I add the table names before the field, it asks me to enter a parameter, so I left it out. Here's what I have finally, hope it's right.

SELECT Last, OrdDate, Orderline.PrID,Orderline.Fabric, Qty, Price
FROM ((Cus INNER JOIN Orders  ON Cus.CID=Orders.CID)
INNER JOIN Orderline  ON Orders.OrdID=Orderline.OrdID) INNER JOIN ProdFabric ON Orderline.Fabric=ProdFabric.Fabric AND OrderLine.Fabric=ProdFabric.Fabric;

Comment: Looks good, except I'm not sure why you join to ProdFabric on Fabric twice. Can you join to ProdFabric on PrID? If you really need to join on Fabric, join on PrID *and* Fabric like this: INNER JOIN ProdFabric ON Orderline.PrID = ProdFabric.PrID AND Orderline.Fabric = ProdFabric.Fabric;  Other than that you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "AND ON" exists like you use it in your query.
You have to specify each join on its own.

```
SELECT ...
FROM cus INNER JOIN orders ON cus.cid = orders.cid
         INNER JOIN orderline ON orders.orderid = orderline.orderid
...
```

or you can also specify the join in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM cus INNER JOIN orders 
         INNER JOIN orderline
...
WHERE cus.cid = orders.cid
  AND orders.orderid = orderline.orderid
...
```

Also: INNER JOIN are 2 words ;-)

Comment: Of course... didn't see the more obvious error... INNER JOIN is not in one word... I updated the answer.

Comment: Now I am getting this error message:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Cus.CID=Orders.CID INNER JOIN Orderline ON Orders.OrdID=Orderline.OrdID INNER JOIN ProdFabric ON Orderline.Fabric=ProdFabric.Fabric'.

Comment: Try to add the parentheses like Adam suggested, and otherwise try specifying the join in the where clause like my second example.